# How do you parse 2-digit year date with time?

Tags: java, parsing, date

Sorry for bringing this up, but I don't see it. I have date+time in such format:

> dd-MM-yy HH:mm

For example

> 15-11-11 09:36

(at the time of writing, it indicates date 5 days ago). When I try to run:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm").parse("15-11-11 09:36")
```

I get exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15-11-11 09:36"

At first I thought it is something with year (despite (-80,+20) boundary -- according to documentation). Well, maybe, but when I remove time (from string and pattern), the date is recognized correctly.

Does anyone see what I don't see?

### Update

My system (Linux) short date format:

> YYYY-MM-DD

long:

> WEEKDAY DD MONTH YYYY

and time:

> HH:MM:SS

However I thought the purpose of giving the pattern is to be locale independent.

Out of curiosity I added ":ss" to pattern and ":01" to string, still exception.

Comment: Works fine for me. What's your locale, although I'm not sure if that would matter.

Comment: Same here, no exception. Could it possibly have anything to do with locales?

Comment: Of course, you don't have to use SimpleDateFormat.  You could split the string on non-digits.  eg `mystring.split("\\D");`

Comment: @mike jones, sure but this would mean inventing a wheel each time I spot a problem with a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can just estimate but I think that you copy/pasted either format fragment or the date. And by mistake inserted different semicolon character in both cases. The characters look the same but are different.

So, I suggest you to take your working example without time and *type* manually `HH:mm` and `10:36`. If it does not work, I am really sorry. :(. If it does try first to change `10` to `09`. This is to be sure that it takes numbers with leading zeros.

Comment: I don' understand what you are saying, I copied actual code, what you see is what I have. Initially I had "11", but I changed it something <10, to find out if "11" hour next to "11" make the difference.

Comment: I mean that there are several characters in Unicode table that look like `:`. So, I just suggested that probably one of them is "wrong" in your code.

Comment: This caught me off-guard, but you were right -- the bug was in what you **DON'T** see, yes, the spaces. In pattern there was a space, but in string it was hard space, visually identical :-( When I copied the code to SO, the engine treated them the same...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");  

System.out.println("Formatted date: " + df.format(date));
```

Comment: Um, why? His current code is just fine; there's something else going on.

Comment: The OP wants to parse a given date string. Your example shows how to format a given Date object...

Comment: Siva is right. `SimpleDateFormat` implement 2 opposite operations. If format works it result must be parsable. The result of `format` can give a tip what was wrong.

Comment: Formatted date: 20-11-11 19:34, so this way is fine.

Comment: Thanks AlexR & Macias. +1 for explaning.

Comment: Siva, so what's up? If you can format the date try to put the formatted date to string and immediately parse it. I believe it will work.